# How to Get JSON values Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

Learning Days
Code to the get the data in JSON Format

```
#...
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
response = {
    "version": "5.2",
    "user_type": "online",
    "user": list(cursor),
}
response = json.dumps(response, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
print(response)
# ...
```

This produces output as

```
{
"version": "5.2",
"user_type": "online",
"user":
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "id": 50
    },
    {
        "name": "Mark",
        "id": 57
    }
]
}

print(response["user"]) - TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How do i access the values in JSON

Comment: `json.dumps` returns a string.

Comment: yes it return a string gone through the docs

Comment: Well, you cannot do `response["user"]` on a string `response`. What you want to do is `response["user"]` on the old value of `response` before you turned it into a string using `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json.dumps return a string, need a small conversion something like this, not sure is this the exact method to do

Solution:

```
response = JSONEncoder().encode(response )
response = JSONDecoder().decode(response )
response = json.loads(response )
print(response['user'[0]['id'])
```

Comment: Why would you decode a JSON string right after encoding it?

Comment: well, newbie, but this works, don't know how. can someone explain why this works ?